# Pass method as parameter and using in a forEach loop

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I would like to call a delete function while looping through a list of devices.  The devices can be one of two types - SmsPhone or Email.  Can this be achieved with one of the Java 8 FunctionalInterfaces?

```
// leaving out implementation details for simplicity
public class SmsPhone extends Device {
}

public class Email extends Device {
}

public class Device {
    private String contact;
    public String getContact() { return contact; }
    public void setContact(String contact) { this.contact = contact; }
}

public class MyService {

    public void updateEmail(String username, Collection<Email> allEmails, Collection<String> selectedEmails) {
        updateUserDevices(username, allEmails, selectedEmails);
    }

    public void updateSms(String username, Collection<SmsPhone> allPhones, Collection<String> selectedPhones) {
        updateUserDevices(username, allPhones, selectedPhones);
    }

    private void updateUserDevices(final String username, Collection<Device> devices, Collection<String> contacts) {

        // put all the device contact info in the list and then filter out the ones in the given devices collection.
        devices.stream()
            .map(d -> d.getContact())
            .filter(s -> !contacts.contains(s))
            .forEach(s -> /***Call either deleteEmail() or deleteSms()***/);
    }

    private void deleteEmail(String email) {}
    private void deleteSms(String sms) {}

}
```

Comment: If I didn't miss sth. the condition for deleting/keeping the object is missing here

Comment: It is all strings, so why do you have `deleteEmail` and `deleteSms` in the first place instead of just `delete`?

Comment: the ones to keep are filtered out in the filter() method.

Comment: @Fildor yes, they are all strings, however they are removed using different methods calling an API.  I could have a universal delete(), but would have to parse the String to check for '@' and then call a different delete method depending on that result.

Comment: Then you can return the collection with the ones to keep. Thats why you filter it

Comment: @ArthurEirich I'm filtering the ones I want to keep out and then removing the remaining contacts.

Comment: Ah, I think I see now.  Are you saying to use the updateUserDevices method simply as a way to filter an return the devices to delete (or keep)?

Comment: @acvcu Yes, you filter your device list and sort out those which meet the condition you are passing to the filter method. By calling forEach you actually are already looping through the devices either to keep or to delete

Comment: yes, but I was hoping there was a way to delete the device within the forEach of updateUserDevices(), which I don't think is possible since there is a specific delete method depending on the type of Device. I am already filtering out the ones to keep and then looping through the ones to delete: filter(s -> !contacts.contains(s))

Comment: I think, you can derive from the other comments, that your design is questionable. Nevertheless for your specific issue, don’t use `map` when it implies loosing information, you need in a later step. Just use `devices.stream() .filter(d -> !contacts.contains(d.getContact())) .forEach(device -> /* whatever */);`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
private void updateUserDevices(final String username, Collection<Device> devices, Collection<String> contacts) {

    // put all the device contact info in the list and then filter out the ones in the given devices collection.
    devices.stream()
        .filter(d -> !contacts.contains(d.getContact()))
        .forEach(MyService::delete);
}

private void delete(Device d) {
    String contact = d.getContact();
    if (d.isEmail()) {
        deleteEmail(contact);
    } else {
        deleteSms(contact);
    }
}

private void deleteEmail(String email) {}
private void deleteSms(String sms) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shoud make `Device` an abstract class with an abstract `delete` method:

```
public abstract class Device {
    private String contact;
    public String getContact() { return contact; }
    public void setContact(String contact) { this.contact = contact; }
    public abstract void delete();
}
```

This way you can call `delete` on any `Device` without knowing its kind and each subclass of `Device` can implement `delete` their own way.